# "no hell" or "no hang"?

Tags: meaning

I think "NO HELL" can be used to describe something that isn't bad, or not very tasty. Like a meal that tastes so-so but looked good. I heard at the dinner table last night that my wife said the corn was "no hang". What is the correct expression? Has anyone else heard different?

Comment: Where are you located?  I've never heard either expression.

Comment: HELL NO is used more than NO HELL.

Comment: Can you give a full sentence with it in, so that we can get proper context for its use.

Comment: It's a phrase distinct to northern Ontario (Sudbury, Timmins). I grew up there hearing it quite often in the 1970s and 80s. People in southern Ontario have never heard of it. Do people use it elsewhere?

Answer (score 3):

I live in Ontario, Canada.  I have heard 'it's no hell' from many people and it seemed a little more common years ago. It was a phrase to describe something that wasn't very good.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, it's a perfectly appropriate answer to the question that was asked.

Answer (score 2):

I've never come across either 'no hell' or 'no hang' in the UK, though I can work out the meaning in context.

'Promised so much but delivered so little' might be appropriate

Comment: I agree. It's not common.

Answer (score 2):

I live in Ontario and use this pharse and have heard it often. It means it's not bad, but not great.

Comment: Interesting answer. Do you have any sense of how widespread the usage is? Also can you specify what part of Ontario you're talking about (Windsor, Toronto, Kingston, Ottawa, Sudbury, or whatever)? Thanks!